# Debugging in Visual Studio Code returns [Errno 2] No such file or directory, however works fine when running from cmd

Tags: python, json, google-sheets, visual-studio-code, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to connect to the Google Sheets API using this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cnPlKLEGR7E
When I try to run the code in Visual Studio Code I get an error saying that the cred.json file does not exist. 
However, when I run the same code in cmd, the code executes as it should and shows my data from my online datasheet.

I have already tried launching VSC in admin mode and adding 
`"python.terminal.executeInFileDir": true` in the .vscode settings file.
Nothing seems to work.

This is the code that is being executed.

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
def sheets():
    scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
    creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("creds.json", scope)
    client = gspread.authorize(creds)
    sheet = client.open("businessdata").sheet1
    data = sheet.get_all_records()
    print(data)
```

I was hoping to be able to run the code in VSC so that I wouldn't have to run through cmd every time I need to test my code.
Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: Where is creds.json relative to this Python file and where is this file relative to the folder you opened in VS Code?

Comment: They reside in the same folder:
C:\Name\OneDrive - Company Name\Folder\Python\Game\
I have a suspicion that it may be because of the OneDrive folder name, but couldn't find issues related to that online.

Comment: And how are you having the Python extension run your code? You shouldn't need `"python.terminal.executeInFileDir": true` as Python itself automatically puts `.` on `sys.path`. And I assume that folder you specified is what you're directly opening as your workspace in VS Code?

Comment: Yes, I am running the all the files in the same workspace in VS Code. 
I have tried to run through some setup guides on youtube to see if I installed everything correctly, and I follow the same procedure as them.

Comment: unfortunately without knowing how oauth2client resolves file locations I can't provide any specific VS Code guidelines, but basically when you run a file via VS Code it doesn't change the working directory so if you can execute in-place for your code then it should work. You can take the command the debugger send to the terminal, strip it down to just a `python` call and see if it works that way. If it does then there might be a bad interaction between the debugger and oauth2client